# Cloud shell editor not working in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In one of my account the Cloud shell is working fine but cloud shell editor is not working on Google Chrome. I tried to open the same in Firefox and it is working perfectly. Also, I tried the same on different laptop and issue still persist for google chrome.

Either it keeps on trying to connect or I get the error shown below:

[image: Error screenshot]

Has anyone faced such issue and has any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

**File Editor runs on Theia IDE and requires third party cookies to work** (Theia got incorporated into Cloud Shell quite recently).

Workaround for this is to click the "eye" icon in the right if the address bar and then "site not working ?" and "allow cookies".

There's already an [issue opened](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164330824) up at Google's Issuetracker for this and Google is aware of this but feel free to +1 yurself and paste any comments.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Note: @Wojtek_B's answer absolutely works, but is temporary when using an Incognito window.*

The other way that I preferred to use was to make this permanent by adding the Cloud Shell URL to my Chrome settings under the *Sites that can always use cookies* section.

Make sure to check the "Including third-party cookies on this site" box (see screenshot below).

[image: Adding a site that allows cookies to Chrome]